# iPhone Splash Screen not loading

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, splash-screen, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am developing a jquery mobile app and I'm trying to load a splash screen and for the life of me can't work out why its not loading.

Here is my code

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://maps.mappingsa.com.au:81/DestinationRiverland/images/icon.png">
                <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
                    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
                        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://maps.mappingsa.com.au:81/DestinationRiverland/images/splash.png">

                            <title>Dest River</title>
```

I can link to the images no worries and the touch icon works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to have a png file according to the pixel size of you iPhone or iPad and give the name of the File 
Default.png it works

Answer (score 0):

Another way other than Default.png is by simply dragging and dropping the PNG files to the following boxes under your target settings. Note that the must be the correct size, 1024x768 for landscape and 768x1024 for portrait.

[image]

Comment: unless he's using PhoneGap, but that's not tagged nor mentioned in his question

Comment: thanks for the answers I solved the problem it was the image dpi that was the issue

Comment: @user952396 you should answer your own question with what solved your problem and accept it.